# No grub after installing ubuntu 14 or mint 17

Tags: ubuntu, grub

Today i just received a new internal hard Hard drive for my HP Elitebook 840 G2
So i installed Ubuntu 14.04LTS, the installation was successful then i rebooted and i see no grub and Ubuntu not starting.
It  tells me i dont have an operator system installed.
The only way to start to start Ubuntu for me is to go in the menu EFI/boot/grubx64.efi and press enter into this.
Same things for Linux Mint.
I would like to know how to install Ubuntu or Mint and having the grub ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to Reinstall Grub using a Ubuntu Live CD.

Mount the partition your Ubuntu Installation is on

```
sudo mount /dev/sdXY /mnt
```

example:`sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`

Now bind the directories that grub needs access to to detect other operating systems:

```
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev 
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts 
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
```

chroot, install, check, and update grub

```
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sdX
grub-install --recheck /dev/sdX
update-grub
```

exit the chrooted system and unmount everything.

```
exit 
sudo umount /mnt/sys 
sudo umount /mnt/proc 
sudo umount /mnt/dev/pts 
sudo umount /mnt/dev 
sudo umount /mnt
```

Reboot your system.